# Merging files displays only one file in c#

Tags: c#, file, merge

I am making simple file merging program using FileReader and creating new merged file with extension .mrg.

When i try to merge text file using program it merges the text file and gives .mrg file.

When i open this file with notepad it gives me content of both the text file.

But when i try merging image file it gives me .mrg file and when i try to open it with paint it shows only one image.

while i think it must give merged image.

Same thing happens in the case of Excel file and Pdf file.

**My doubt is whether this is correct or not?
And if it's correct than why it shows only one file?**

Size of the merged file is also the sum of all the file size.

**My problem is not to solve the issue but i want to understand why it happens?**

Comment: And what would you expect the merged image / PDF / Excel file to look like? These are binary formats, and merging the data blindly will produce meaningless output.

Comment: @NiravKamani: Basically, any merging application needs to know the implementation specifics of the file format it's trying to merge. There is no such thing as an application that can meaningfully merge unknown file formats!

Comment: @Baldrick can you tell me the reason behind that?

Comment: @NiraKamani: Hope my answer below clarifies it somewhat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging needs to have knowledge of the format it's working with.

There is no such thing as a merging utility that can work without this specific knowledge.

Expecting otherwise would be like glueing 2 CDs together, and expecting the CD drive to read the combined contents of the disks.

**Example**

Assume your merge strategy is simply to *append bytes from file 1 to file 2*.

This will work fine for plain text documents, sure. There is no *internal structure* within these files.

But imagine now the file is structured like this (typical kind of binary format):

> [Header area | Data block | Trailing bytes| End]

Many image formats look vaguely like this (but they all are still different from each other).

When an application (like Paint) opens the file, it looks in the header area, finds out things like the size of the data block, loads it, etc, draws the image.

What happens if you append 2 such files together, using your strategy of *append bytes from file 1 to file 2*?

What does your merged file look like?

> [Header area | Data block | Trailing bytes| Header area | Data block |
>   Trailing bytes| End]

When Paint looks at this file, it just does the same thing.. opens it, reads the header, loads the first data block (it knows nothing about the second load of data you've added), and shows the first image.

It fact, you're lucky it loads at all. A lot of file formats have **checksums** or **hashcodes** in the header to verify the file is the expected length and the binary has not been altered... but that's a whole different question.

Comment: Any more description.You are really giving good explanation about why problem is raising?

Comment: Exactly which part isn't clear? I can try to expand further if you tell me.

Comment: I completely understand your explanation. I am asking just for more informaion